# Deploying a WCF application in Windows Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture, azure

I'm looking for some **advise / best practices** for setting up a WCF application in Windows Azure.

Currently I have an SQL Azure DB and I want to make some services which need to provide information for iPhone and some other 3rd party products.

**1) How do I develop a WCF application in Windows Azure, using SQL Azure data? 

 2) What is the best architecture to do this and what is the best way to make this secure?**

I'm using C# as language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the WCF Web Role by using the Azure SDK, or you can host your WCF on a worker role as well. It's up to you.

Connect to SQL Azure would be very very similar as what you did to connect to SQL Server, just pay attention to the connection string.

Since you mentioned this WCF will be used for iPhone and some 3rd part application, I strongly recommended you have a look on WCF RESTful Toolkit, and the JSON format. Since for this scenario, RESTful API (or web api) with JSON format would be the best.

Comment: And what about security? SSL?

Comment: The WCF on Azure will be exactly the same as what you are doing on a local server. You can bind the HTTPS on your WCF web role, by using the certificate part in Azure SDK, and the WCF configuration. Alternatively you can bind it with your worker role, but you need to bind your certificate with your port by NETSH command via the Azure startup feature.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post 'Building a Massively Scalable Platform for Consumer Devices on Windows Azure'

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781021.aspx

Should cover your two topics nicely...

Connecting to SQL Azure is easier, you have so many options, ADO.NET, Entity Framework, OData etc..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621789.aspx

Take a look at the Windows Azure Training Kit for more sample on this.